# GAE self.request.environ and server host

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi

I'm trying to obtain the base URL (hostname) of the server in which my appengine app is running on.

Ie something along the lines of

```
wsgiref.util.application_uri(self.request.environ)
```

However it's returning the PATH_INFO which I do not want. Perhaps I'm missing something but even this article states the path info should be omitted. 
http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html

`http://9.latest.my-app.appspot.com`

is basically along the lines of what i'm trying to retrieve. Instead it's returning

`http://9.latest.my-app.appspot.com/my/requested/path`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The request object is a [Webob](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/) request object. As such, you can get the hostname from `self.request.host`, the hostname with protocol from `self.request.host_url`, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the hostname in `os.environ['HTTP_HOST']`.

That won't include the protocol, but it should be easy to parse from the value you've got:

```
base = '/'.join(url.split('/')[:3])
```

or...

```
import urlparse
url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
base = "%s://%s" % (url.scheme, url.hostname)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a solution that is built in to wsgiref rather than parsing the requested URL. This will suffice however

Comment: This is very useful for cases other than wsgi. For instance using [python-requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/) with [BeautifulSoup](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/) and following relative urls. I will, however suggest that you **use url.netloc instead of url.hostname**. Netloc includes the port number when it differs from the defaults of 80 and 443 for http and https respectively.

Comment: If you skim the [docs for urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) you will find that "the return value is actually an instance of a subclass of tuple". This gives you index access to 6 key attributes. (These include netloc, but not hostname, as further evidence of my claim above.) This allows you to get your base with this oneliner `base = '://'.join(urlparse(url)[0:2])` if you `from urlparse import urlparse`. If you are using [python-requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/) get the url like so: `response.request.url`